# Problem with procedure in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create a stored procedure called `UPD_JOBSAL` to update the minimum and 
maximum salaries for a specific job ID in the JOBS table. The procedure should provide three parameters: the job ID, a new minimum salary, and a new maximum salary.

Add exception handling to account for an invalid job ID in the JOBS table.

```
create or replace procedure sma212 (jobidnew varchar2, newmin number, newmax number)
   is
   e exception;
 begin
  update jobs
  set min_salary=newmin, max_salary=newmax
    where job_id=jobidnew;
    if job_id<>jobidnew THEN
   raise e;
 end if;
     exception 
 when e then
 dbms_output.put_line('invalid jobid');
 end;
```

Upon execution shows an error: `job_id` must be declared?

[image: Screengrab 1]

[image: Screengrab 2]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is there a loop?

Comment: Is this homework? That's allowed but please disclose it if it is

Comment: @TomV yeh its like practice ..do we require loop compulsory here ?

Comment: `if job_id<>jobidnew THEN raise e;` In what situation do you expect this to occur? Your `UPDATE` statement is neither returning rows, nor would it return a row that doesn't meet your `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: What is the DDL for the table and what is the command string you are executing when you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if job_id<>jobidnew THEN
```

is not part of the `UPDATE` which precedes it, so the identifier `job_id` does not refer to the column by that name but to a separate (undeclared) variable.

The way to test whether the `UPDATE` did anything or not is to test the implicit cursor attribute `SQL%notfound`, as in

```
if SQL%notfound THEN
  RAISE e;
```

The complete procedure definition should be

```
create or replace procedure sma212 (jobidnew varchar2, newmin number, newmax number)
  is
    e exception;
  begin
    update jobs
      set min_salary=newmin, max_salary=newmax
      where job_id=jobidnew;

    if SQL%notfound THEN
      raise e;
    end if;

    exception 
      when e then
        dbms_output.put_line('invalid jobid');
  end;
```

Comment: I missed sql%notfound

Comment: i am just going through tutorailpoint website about sql%notfound. thanksagain